# Linked List Java structure (Generics)

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a LinkedList in java. The structure is simple: the controller (BList class), the node, the information component of the node. 
Now I would like to integrate the use of Generics: the information component of the node should be generic.
I can't understand the following error. Why the compiler expects an Object type if I've specified a generic type `<E>`?

```
Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(newNode.getElement().getUserId());   
                                               ^
  symbol:   method getUserId()
  location: class Object
1 error
```

This is my code. Thanks in advance for you help.

```
public class BList<E> {
    private Node head;

    public BList() {
        this.head = null;
    }

    public Node insert(E element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element);

        newNode.setSucc(this.head);
        this.head = newNode;

        return newNode; 
    }
}

class Node<E> {
    private Node succ;

    private E element;

    public Node(E element) {
        this.succ = null;
        this.element = element;
    }

    public void setSucc(Node node) {
        this.succ = node;
    }

    public void setElement(E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public E getElement() {
//      return this.element; // ?
        return (E) this.element;
    }
}

class Element {
    private int userId;

    public Element(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }
}      

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BList<Element> bList = new BList<Element>();

        Node newNode = bList.insert(new Element(1));
// error happens here!      
        System.out.println(newNode.getElement().getUserId());

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought: you seem to be holding the Node class as package-private and the head-node as private in your BList implementation. So why are you returning the Node which was create in your insert method? Wouldn't that be to expose the internal representation of your BList?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the raw form of `Node` in 2 places:

1. The return type of `BList`'s `insert` method.  Return a `Node<E>` instead of a `Node`.
2. The declaration of `newNode` in `main`.  Declare it as `Node<Element>` instead of `Node`.

Because the raw form of `Node` was used, `Object` is now the return type, which doesn't have a `getUserId` method.  Pre-generics code (before Java 1.5) would cast the result of `getElement` to an `Element` before calling `getUserId`, but making the above changes is the way to solve this problem with generics.

Comment: insert should probably also return a Node<E> as well

Comment: @AmirAfghani:  If you wanted to get pedantic, `insert` *should* be returning either a `boolean` to indicate its success, or nothing at all.  For the example, though, you are quite correct.

Comment: @AmirAfghani I had the wrong method in item 1.  Corrected.  Thanks.

Comment: I agree @Makoto - I wasn't trying to be pedantic.

Comment: Thanks guys, i've fixed the code. You are right @Makoto, the add method of the official Java LikedList returns a boolean. Is this the right way to use generics in this context?